# Creating exact replica of video file[ffmpeg]

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have written some code using ffmpeg's library which decodes every frame of video file, does some manipulation on it and finally encode and mux the frame to new container.this all works. 
The problem i am trying to solve here is how to make the output file have exact stream settings as input file.

if I run ffmpeg -i on my files I get following - 

1)Input File -

```
Duration: 00:00:30.95, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1195 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], **996 kb/s**, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, **50 tbc (default)**
    <br>Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-30 06:33:24
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
```

2)Output file -

```
Duration: 00:00:30.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1225 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], **1032 kb/s**, 25.03 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, **100 tbc (default)**<br>
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

3)If i run my code again on above output file to generate another output file then that file looks like this-

```
Duration: 00:00:30.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1264 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], **1071 kb/s**, 25.03 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, **200 tbc (default)**
```

Notice the bitrate and TBC is changing everytime i run my code.

How should I configure my encoder to make the output file identical to input file ? the current code for configuring encoder looks like this -

```
    c = out_stream->codec;
    c->codec_id                = inputStream->codec->codec_id;
    c->bit_rate                = inputStream->codec->bit_rate;

    /* Resolution must be a multiple of two. */
    c->width                   = inputStream->codec->width;
    c->height                  = inputStream->codec->height;
    c->gop_size                = inputStream->codec->gop_size;

    c->time_base               = inputStream->codec->time_base;
    out_stream->time_base      = inputStream->time_base;

        av_stream_set_r_frame_rate(out_stream,av_stream_get_r_frame_rate(inputStream));
    out_stream->avg_frame_rate = inputStream->avg_frame_rate;

    c->pix_fmt                 = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    c->sample_aspect_ratio.num = inputStream->codec->sample_aspect_ratio.num;
    c->sample_aspect_ratio.den = inputStream->codec->sample_aspect_ratio.den;
    c->ticks_per_frame         = inputStream->codec->ticks_per_frame;
    c->profile                 = inputStream->codec->profile;
    out_stream->duration       = inputStream->duration;
```